# Got CompatibilityError while installing pods objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

Below is the error I am getting when I run

```
pod install    

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods-core/standard_error.rb:88:in `message': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:367:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

And below is my PodFile
    platform :ios, ‘8.4’

```
target 'PodProject' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1' 
end

target 'PodProjectTests' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
end
```

I have tried updating "gem"

Comment: open your podfile with xcode and replace `\`` with `'` it maybe text editor error

Comment: @HamzaAnsari thanks. It worked.